# There exists a vector space with exactly two vectors in it?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the answer is NO. and I know it has something to do the with 10 rules of vectors space, but I just can't prove it. Any hints/solution would be appreciated!

Comment: How about the field with 2 elements?

Comment: Think about how you can use those two vectors to produce a vector which is different from both of them. Be sure to prove your result is different using the properties of a vector space.

Comment: You know that the $0$ vector must be in all vector spaces (i.e. a unit vector). If there is only one other vector in the vector space, it must necessarily be its own inverse. Over what field might that vector space exist?

Comment: $\# \{0, v, -v\} \neq 2$

Comment: @ViníciusFerraz as has been pointed out sometimes it does.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes. Consider $\mathbb Z_2$ as a vector space with $\mathbb Z_2$ as the underlying field and the natural operations.

It is true however that no vector space over any other field (including $\mathbb R$) has exactly two vectors. This is because all finite dimensional vector spaces over the field $\mathbb F$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb F^n$.